# Backspace not working properly with accents in intellij's terminal

Tags: terminal, intellij-idea

I keep getting issues with the terminal where backspace doesn't work as intended and what I see is not what is executed. For example here, I mistyped `git pû` + `<Backspace>` + `ull` + `<Enter>` and I get this:

[image]

The `^` key is close to the `P` on a French keyboard so it happens a lot. I think it's due to a conflict between the encoding of the display and the actual encoding of the terminal. It's [known](https://aide.bancel.org/codes_utf8_caracteres_accentues.php)  among French devs that an `Ã` is most likely the result of UTF-8 encoded accents read with a different encoding, showing up as two characters like `Ã©` instead of `é`, or `Ã»` instead of `û`.

So a single backspace only erases `»` it seems, if I backspace twice and get this:

[image]

Which is not much better if you ask me, it's still really annoying. Especially with `git branch -b`, then I get a branch with a misspelled name that I have to delete and recreate.

How can I make the terminal display exactly what it's about to run? It works fine in the normal git terminal (Git bash), the problem only happens in Intellij's terminal.

Comment: What shell are you running? Does it have decent line editing capabilities (like left-right arrows moving the cursor inside the line)? I assume it doesn't. If so then `stty iutf8` should fix it.

Comment: @egmont I use the default git sh terminal, `...\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe`. It does support left-right arrows moving the cursor inside the line. `stty iutf8` didn't solve the issue, I already had `-imaxbel iutf8` when running `stty`.

Comment: Oh, I see. My guess didn't work. I'm not familiar with IntelliJ or "git sh" terminal, so I'm afraid I cannot help you here. It could easily be an ISO-8859-1 <-> UTF-8 mismatch somewhere, but no idea where, and you also suspected this, so nothing new.